# Automapper- How can I map complex object form source to a flattened properties in destination?

Tags: .net, automapper, flatten

**source** These are the Source classes. Prop2 is a complex type that I want to be flattened in my destination.

```
public class Source1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Source2> Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Source2
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Prop4 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

**Destination** This is the destination class

```
public class Destination
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Prop4 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

**Expected Result** should be a collection of all the properties in the destination class

```
{
 [
   prop1: "abc1",
   prop3: efg1,
   prop4: 123.4,
   prop5: true
 ],

 [
   prop1: "abc2",
   prop3: efg2,
   prop4: 123.5,
   prop5: false
 ],

 [
   prop1: "abc3",
   prop3: efg3,
   prop4: 123.6,
   prop5: true
 ],

 [
   prop1: "abc4",
   prop3: efg4,
   prop4: 123.7,
   prop5: false
 ],

 ........
 ........
 ........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source2,Destination>().ForMember(d=>d.Prop1, o=>o.ResolveUsing((s,_,__,context)=>context.Items["Prop1"]));
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var source = new Source1 { Prop1="1", Prop2 = new List<Source2> { new Source2 {}, new Source2 {}, new Source2 {} }};
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Destination>>(source.Prop2, opts=>opts.Items["Prop1"]=source.Prop1).Dump();
```

Comment: Awesome! I will try it out.